# Compiling C with JNI for Raspberry Pi 2 (wrong ELF class)

Tags: java, c, gcc, raspberry-pi, java-native-interface

I am trying to compile basic C code with `JNI` for `Rpi2`. I was trying to do it directly in `rpi` with `GCC`. I have tried many different switches, but nothing is working and I am still getting:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /tmp/libTestLibraryWrapper7702387558318276188.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
/tmp/libTestLibraryWrapper7702387558318276188.so: 
/tmp/libTestLibraryWrapper7702387558318276188.so: 
wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
```

I am using:

`gcc -shared -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -c -g -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include/linux -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/testJava.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/testJava.o testJava.c`

I am a little stuck right now, so any kind of hint will be appreciated.

Comment: It appears you created a 64-bit shared object.  If you're running a 32-bit JVM, you need a 32-bit shared object.  `gcc -m32 ...` will produce a 32-bit shared object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using samples from here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

I am able to run the code without any issues at:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS    : 2.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware    : BCM2708
Revision    : 0010
Serial      : 00000000ee4a3dc2
```

Just do following:

```
git clone https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook.git
cd jnicookbook/recipes/recipeNo001/
export JAVA_HOME=$WHEREVER_YOUR_JAVA_IS
make test
```

Should give you result:

```
make test
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/bin/java -Djava.library.path=:./lib -cp target recipeNo001.HelloWorld
library: :./lib
Hello world!
```